# Despite putting my main.py and android.txt files in storage/emulated/0, Kivy doesn't recognize it as a project

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Recently I've been trying to use Kivy to run some of my Python code on Android phones(more specifically, my OnePlus 3). But although I've followed the directions regarding putting the android.txt file and the main.py file in storage/emulated/0/kivy, the app still says that no projects are detected.

I think the reason why this is happening is because the full directory of where I'm putting the files is "This PC\ONEPLUS A3000\Internal shared storage\T-Mobile Content Transfer\storage\emulated\0\kivy". I believe that this is the wrong directory due to the fact that I'm placing the files under "T-Mobile Content Transfer" (an app that I had used a couple months ago but have uninstalled). Maybe there is another place I'm supposed to put the files, but so far, I've spent a couple days looking but haven't found any.

I'm fairly new to this, so I apologize if my question is somewhat stupid. Thanks!

The directory in which I placed my python and .txt file:

[image: The directory in which I placed my python and .txt file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put the main.py and android.txt files in a `kivy` folder that is located in your phone's home directory
That is:  `"This PC\ONEPLUS A3000\Internal shared storage\kivy"`